# Asymptotic distribution of a Maximum Likelihood Estimator using the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be a random sample from a population $X$ having probability density function
$$f(x;\vartheta)=\vartheta\,x^{\vartheta -1}\,I_{(0,1)}(x)$$
$$\vartheta>0\qquad\qquad I_{(0,1)}(x)=
\begin{cases}
1\qquad\text{if }x\in(0,1)\\
0\qquad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Find:

1. $\hat{\vartheta}_n$, the MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimator) of the parameter $\vartheta$
2. the approximate distribution of $\hat{\vartheta}_n$ for $n$ big

While I'm pretty confident on how to solve the first point, I'd like some advice on the second one.

---

**1.**

To find the MLE $\hat{\vartheta}_n$, the *likelihood function* is calculated:
$$\mathscr{L}(\underline{x};\vartheta) = \vartheta^n\,\left( x_1 \times\dots\times x_n \right)^{\vartheta -1} = \vartheta^n\,\left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{\vartheta -1} \qquad\qquad(0<x_i<1,\, \forall\,i=1,2,\dots,n)$$
The first derivative with respect to $\vartheta$ is
$$\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}(\underline{x};\vartheta)}{\partial\vartheta} = \vartheta^{n-1}\,\left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{\vartheta -1}\left[ n+\vartheta\,\log{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)}\right]$$
and $\hat{\vartheta}_n$ is obtained solving for
$$\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}(\underline{x};\vartheta)}{\partial\vartheta} = 0\quad \implies \quad \hat{\vartheta}_n = -\frac{n}{\log{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)}}$$
To be precise, it should now be checked that
$$\left. \frac{\partial^2\mathscr{L}(\underline{x};\vartheta)}{\partial\vartheta^2}\right|_{\vartheta=\hat{\vartheta}_n} < 0$$
In order to do so, the second derivative with respect to $\vartheta$ is calculated:
$$\frac{\partial^2\mathscr{L}(\underline{x};\vartheta)}{\partial\vartheta^2} = \underbrace{\vartheta^{n-2}\,\left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{\vartheta -1}}_{\Gamma}\underbrace{\left[ n(n-1)+2n\vartheta\log{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)}+\vartheta^2\log^2{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)}\right]}_{\Delta}$$
$\Gamma$ is always positive, hence we only need to evaluate
$$\left.\Delta\right|_{\vartheta=\hat{\vartheta}_n} = -n <0$$

---

**2.**

To obtain the approximate distribution of $\hat{\vartheta}_n$ for $n$ big (a.k.a. the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\vartheta}_n$ for $n\to\infty$), I thought of applying *Cramér's Theorem* for the asymptotic normality of the MLE.
This assures that 
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\vartheta}_n-\vartheta\right)\xrightarrow{d}\mathscr{N}(0,1/I(\vartheta))$$
where $I(\vartheta)$ is *Fisher information*, calculated after simple but tedious algebra:
$$I(\vartheta) = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\vartheta}\log{f(x;\vartheta)} \right)^2\right] = \frac{1}{\vartheta^2}$$
**MY QUESTION**

While the procedure presented above to obtain the asymptotic distribution is completely general and should be correct (please tell me if it's not), I was wondering if there is any way to straightforwardly apply the *Central Limit Theorem* (CLT) to the variable
$$\hat{\vartheta}_n = -\frac{n}{\log{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)}}$$
in order to obtain the same result, since $\hat{\vartheta}_n$ can be *almost* re-written as the sum of (the $\log$ of) iid variables:
$$\hat{\vartheta}_n = -\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \log{x_i}}$$

Any idea/suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't really want to write out the details, so instead of making an answer I will just refer you to the delta method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method Basically you already know that $\frac{\sum -\log(X_i)}{n}$ is asymptotically normal by CLT (it is just the average of some iid variables after all) and then you can use the delta method to determine the distribution of the reciprocal of that. I encourage you to answer your own question with this information in hand.

Comment: Cramer's theorem is a straight forward combination of   the CLT, the continuous mapping theorem, and the uniform LLN.  This last ingredient  is needed to pass from $\hat \theta$ solving an equation of form $\bar g(\hat \theta)=0$ (where $\bar g$ is a sample average of data-dependent functions) to one for form $\hat\theta\approx h(\bar T)$ where $h$ is a non-random function.

Comment: @Ian thank you very much, I'll look into that and try and write an answer!

Comment: @kimchi-lover thank you as well :) If I understood correctly, what you suggest is very similar, I'll check that too!

Comment: What kimchilover said is basically what I said phrased in terms of the theorems that back it up.

Comment: @Ian I agree with your most recent comment.  I hope you did not take mine as an attempt to contradict your first comment, which I didn't see until I posted mine.

Comment: @kimchilover You're good, I think both of our comments are helpful here; we are basically saying the same thing in different language, but it can only be helpful to have more stuff to look up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated, thanks to the *Cramer's Theorem* it is found that
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\vartheta}_n-\vartheta\right)\xrightarrow{d}\mathscr{N}(0,\vartheta^2)$$
The same result can be found applying in a more straightforward manner the CLT and the [Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).

The MLE is rewritten as
$$\hat{\vartheta}_n = \left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n -\log{x_i}}{n}\right)^{-1} = \left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{n}\right)^{-1} = (\bar{Y}_n)^{-1}$$
with $y_i := -\log{x_i}$ and $\bar{Y}_n := \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{n}$.

The CLT assures that $\bar{Y}_n$ is asymptotically normal - since it is the sum of iid variables with finite variance (this will soon be proved) - and so that
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar{Y}_n - \mu_y)\xrightarrow{d}\mathscr{N}\left(0,\sigma_y^2\right)$$
where
$$\mu_y = \mathbb{E}(y) = -\int_0^1 log{(x)}\,\vartheta\,x^{\vartheta - 1}\,\,\mathcal{d}x = \frac{1}{\vartheta}$$
$$\mathbb{E}(y^2) = \int_0^1 log^2{(x)}\,\vartheta\,x^{\vartheta - 1}\,\,\mathcal{d}x = \frac{2}{\vartheta^2}$$
$$\sigma_y^2 = \mathbb{E}(y^2) - \left( \mathbb{E}(y) \right)^2 = \frac{1}{\vartheta^2}$$
Finding, in the end, that
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar{Y}_n - \frac{1}{\vartheta})\xrightarrow{d}\mathscr{N}\left(0,\frac{1}{\vartheta^2}\right)$$
Now, applying the *Delta method*, also the following must be true:
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\left(\bar{Y}_n\right)^{-1} - \left(\frac{1}{\vartheta}\right)^{-1}\right)\xrightarrow{d}\mathscr{N}\left(0,\frac{1}{\vartheta^2}\cdot\left[\left.\frac{d x^{-1}}{dx}\right|_{x=\frac{1}{\vartheta}} \right]^2\right) = \mathscr{N}\left(0,\frac{1}{\vartheta^2}\cdot \vartheta^4\right)$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\vartheta}_n - \vartheta\right)\xrightarrow{d}\mathscr{N}\left(0,\vartheta^2\right)$$

This is the result already found applying the *Cramer's Theorem*.

---

*[many thanks to [kimchi lover](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/457779/kimchi-lover) and even more to [Ian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83396/ian) for helping through the whole process]*

Comment: The derivative of $1/x$ at $x=1/\theta$ is $-\theta^2$, which upon squaring gives $\theta^4$, giving the same result as Cramer's theorem.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I got the formula wrong and now I see why that couldn't be it!

Comment: By the way, you can also accept your own answer.

Comment: @Ian it says I can't do that yet